# Django: How to override the MIME type of a user uploaded file?

Tags: python, django, mime-types, content-type

Users on my web dev forum can upload HTML files as attachments to their posts, to show their code. This is done through a Django FileField. How can I ensure that these uploads are then served with "text/plain" content type, rather than "text/html"? Because the purpose is for other people to look at the source code, not the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django's [`striptags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) for stripping HTML tags.